# Preserve Arabic Text from HTML

Tags: python, html, nlp, decode, encode

I am trying to get the following code (Python 3.7.6 - Windows 10) to strip off the HTML tags and leave me with the Arabic text. The code works if I am working with English text.

The issues seems to be related to when I change the data type to STRing (line#12). I use the 'find' command (line#15) to determine the start of the arabic text I want to extract; minus the HTML tags.The 'find' command (line#15) only works on string data-types

```
1   import urllib.request, urllib.error, urllib.parse
2   import sys
3   import re
4   url = 'https://www.altafsir.com/printpage.asp?status=Paging2&FileName=C%3A%5CITGWebsites%5CAltafsir%5CTafasir%5CPreCompiled%5CAl%5FRazi%5C04%2D002%2D029%2ETXT&Page=Tafasir&Sora=2&Ayah=29'
5   response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
6   HTML = response.read()
10  type(HTML)
11  len(HTML)
12  HTML = str(HTML)
13  type(HTML)
14  len(HTML)
15  startLoc = HTML.find("<font color")
16  endLoc = HTML.rfind("<!--TEXTAREA")
17  HTML = HTML[startLoc:endLoc]
18  inside = 0
19  text = ''
20  for char in HTML:
21          if char == '<':
22              inside = 1
23          elif (inside == 1 and char == '>'):
24              inside = 0
25          elif inside == 1:
26              continue
27          else:
28              text += char
29  wordlist = re.compile(r'\W+', re.UNICODE).split(text)
```

Searching around there are several references made to Beautiful Soup. I would like to avoid that app/library and achieve my solution using 'native' code.

Additional searching has suggested the use of encode/decode syntax. But all of the examples I have found are either related to Python 2.x or don't seem to work (for me).

I have been struggling with this for a couple of days now and am out of options.

PS - The above code has been taken from the very useful site ([From HTML to List of Words](https://programminghistorian.org/en/lessons/from-html-to-list-of-words-1))

Comment: First things first, why aren't you using an HTML parser? _I would like to avoid that app/library and achieve my solution using 'native' code._ Why? What does _'native' code_ mean? In any case, you haven't explained what the issue actually is here. Finally, variable and function names should generally follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Comment: Thank you @AMC for your useful comments. To elaborate further, the issue is that I am able to obtain the desired Arabic text/data_stream (along with HTML tags) and store it in a byte data_type (or save it as a .html file). However, in order to remove the HTML tags I have to convert the data-stream into a string data-type after which I loose the Arabic text (it is no longer stored/writable as  Arabic text but character encoding e.g. \xc7\xe1\xd4\xed\xc1. Need to look into the HTML parser option you mentioned.

Comment: _Need to look into the HTML parser option you mentioned._ Yes, that's probably for the best. There might be a slight encoding issue here, but it's going to be far more difficult to solve if the HTML handling is needlessly complicated.